# document.write() not working on one machine, works on others

Tags: javascript

I have a customer using one of our scripts to write applet tags to a web page using document.write(). The script works on all our development machines, on all other customer machines and on this customer's home machine. But when run on his work machine, the document.write() does not execute.

Furthermore, the applet tag works perfectly fine if it's written in HTML. It only fails when it's written using document.write. To test, we took a working file that contained barebones HTML, put the applet tag on a single line and enclosed it in a document.write(). The Java plugin didn't initialize, which seems to indicate the document.write is being blocked or failing, unrelated to the applet tag.

What causes should I investigate or what am I missing?

The machine is a Mac running Ubuntu in a virtual machine. The web page that contains the script is being served by Tomcat 7 running on Ubuntu. We tested the page on Firefox and Chrome on the Ubutu virtual machine and on Firefox and Safari on the Mac host machine. None of these ran the file using document.write().

I known document.write is disabled in XHTML, but I don't see how the page could be being parsed as XHTML. The file contains no doctype declarations, so should be being parsed as standard HTML. I also asked if the MIME types had been modified (in case the .htm extension was mapped to an XHTML mime type), but they had not.

I don't have access to his test file, but it was essentially equivalent to:

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>Heat Map Explorer 2012</title>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0">
<script language="JavaScript">
document.write('<applet code="com.labescape.explorer.applet.HeatMapExplorerApplet.class" name="com.labescape.explorer.applet.HeatMapExplorerApplet" archive="resources/lib/explorer-applet-2012.2100.jar" height="100%" width="100%" border="0" mayscript="true"><param name="applet.config@paths" value="" /><param name="config@files" value="interfaces/cluster.xml,maps/machines.xml,resources/config/looks-jgoodies.xml,license.xml" /><param name="config.schema@files" value="resources/schemas/schema-swing.xml,resources/schemas/schema-hme.xml,resources/schemas/schema-looks.xml" /><param name="profiling" value="false" /><param name="java_arguments" value=" -Xmx256m" /><param name="separate_jvm" value="false" /></applet>');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also, we checked the console and there were no syntax errors, so the JavaScript was being parsed correctly. The problem seems to lie with the execution of the method.

Answer (score 2):

No syntax errors in the console does not mean that the javascript was parsed successfully, it could also not have been parsed at all (which would fit in line with the results you are seeing).

I would try changing your script tag by removing the language attribute (it has been [deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html)) and instead use the type attribute with a value of `text/javascript`.

`<script type="text/javascript">document.write(/* Applet Content */);</script>`

Comment: +1 for mentioning the language attribute and linking the deprecation. Saves me the time :)

Answer (score 0):

> "The file contains no doctype declarations, so should be being parsed
>   as standard HTML."

Can you explicitly specify the doctype and test it?

> "Furthermore, the applet tag works perfectly fine if it's written in
>   HTML. It only fails when it's written using document.write."

to test whether the problem is with document.write() or document.write('') try to write something like document.write("hello world")

Answer (score 0):

You must declare the [Document `DOCTYPE`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.2) to avoid browsers **triggering compatibility modes silently**.

But this has its trade-offs: Specially with IE, some doctypes triggers compatibility mode, breaking things that already worked for XHTML. CSS selectors or even javascript code. You need to re-check all styles and functionalities.

- Here is a [Test Code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11443301/1506784) that mentions ` (stackoverflow's document DOCTYPE).
- [Here](https://sites.google.com/site/csskungfu/doctypes-dtd), this another one that mentions HTML 4:

  `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`
- Here is information about `DOCTYPE` and [Compatibility Modes](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/) on IE.