# CSS font-size on Chrome Is Wrong (or IE is)

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

I'm sure everyone's money is on IE being wrong.  There's an equal chance I just don't know what I'm doing.  In IE, all the text (except the H2) gets the font-primary style.  In Chrome, the text in the table gets the wrong font-size (or so I think) - it's described like this in rev tools:

```
color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
display: table-cell;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: normal;
height: 76px;
vertical-align: top;
width: 390px;
```

That font size should be smaller (in my opinion) and is in IE10.

Here's the html:

```
<div class="step-page font-primary">
    <div class="content-panel-0">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="content-panel-1">
        <h2>PERSONAL SHIPPING</h2>
        <span>Descriptions</span>
        <div>
            <table class="content-desc">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Standard</td>
                        <td>Standard transport service</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>Delivery</td>
                        <td>Residential delivery service</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
html
{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

body
{
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    background: none;
}
h2
{
    border: 0px 0px 1px 0px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.content-panel-0
{
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    width: 50px;
}
.content-panel-1
{
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    width: 520px;
}
.content-panel-2
{
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 330px; /*375*/
}
.content-desc td
{
    vertical-align: top
}
.content-desc td:first-child
{
    width: 120px;
}
.font-primary
{
    color: #000000; /*black*/
    font-family: "Arial", "Helvetica", "Sans-serif";
    font-size: 0.750em; /*0.625em; 10px; 12px;*/
    font-weight: normal;
}
.font-primary-bold
{
    color: #000000;
    font-family: "Arial", "Helvetica", "Sans-serif";
    font-size: 0.750em; /*0.625em; 10px; 12px;*/
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Something is amiss - what is it?  FWIW, I believe FF is having the same issue. This points further to an IE issue but, I have to say, the IE behavior is preferable and *seems* more correct to me.

Answer (score 0):

I always do this to myself.  Ask the question, then figure it out.

I needed to add this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Fixed everything.

Comment: I don’t think this really qualifies as an answer without additions that explain what the problem really was and how this solves it.

Comment: I don't know why that fixes it (IE slips into works mode, maybe? And the others treat it... differently?), but it did.

Comment: Maybe start be looking http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11443026/do-modern-browsers-care-about-the-doctype. @jingtao I have to wait longer before I can accept my own answer...