# Can not center align an image element vertically

Tags: css

All:

I am pretty new to CSS layout, currently I have a very simple layout:

```js
http://placehold.it/16/16
```

```css
span.icons {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<span class="icons">
 <img src="http://placehold.it/16/16" />
</span>
</body>
</html>
```

It is so wierd, cos the same HTML works very well when I paste it in this question and run it here, but it just does not work in my local even I use same browser, here is what it looks like in my local:

[image]
[image]

What I want to do is to center-align(only vertically will be fine) the image(16 by 16 pixels), but the image is always at the top-center.

Could anyone help to center align it and a little explain with **WHY it does not work now**?

Thansk

Comment: add `margin: 0 auto;` to your CSS?

Comment: @ochi Thanks. U mean to img?

Comment: Can you add more details about the rest of the HTML and CSS?

Comment: @ochi Update to entire html and css

Comment: Weird, updated my answer to reflect your smaller span and the smaller image centered within the span

Comment: Question: do you want to center the image within the span or the span center in the page?

Comment: @ochi  imge center in the SPAN

Comment: You have not added the `img` rule to your css according to the screenshots

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The specified code works as required BUT I noticed that no DOCTYPE had been declared. This could cause the browser to enter [***Quirks Mode***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode#Mode_differences_and_examples)....which will cause inconsistent page rendering.

Related [Do modern browsers care about the DOCTYPE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11443026/do-modern-browsers-care-about-the-doctype)

```css
span.icons {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<span class="icons">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/nature-q-g-16-16-7.jpg"/>
</span>
```

Of course, these days, I'd use flexbox:

```css
span.icons {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<span class="icons">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/abstract-q-c-16-16-1.jpg">
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks, the code works if I just click to open it in stackoverflow, once I copy it to my local and open in same browser, it does not work again.

Comment: This is so strange, when I paste same html inside stackoverflow's code snippet runner, it works very well while it does not work in my local even I use same browser( if u run the html in my question, it works, that is the same html I copy from my local)!

Comment: not really for this question, I remove all js code and only left html and css, it still the same. I update a screen shot of my local, it use same html here in my quest, but it just does not work

Comment: In dev tools, please select the `img` and show a screenshot of the CSS panel (to the right)

Comment: he added both screenshots but @Kuan, you did not add the `img` rule to your css

Comment: @Paulie_D OMG,  you save me!   Finally we find the difference!! So exciting! But why?

Comment: woot! nice one @Paulie_D

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks, however, after second close watch, I find that the img is not actually strictly centered, it is a little upper located, which means the center of the image is smaller that 20, when I zoom the html,  I can definitely tell the center is not 20

Comment: @Paulie_D Sorry, I mean the position of the center should be (20,20) which is not now.

Answer (score 1):

You mean something along the sides of this?

```css
span.icons {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<span class="icons">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/16/16">
</span>
```

**As to why your code did not work:**

defining DOCTYPE is the difference

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work on my side when I run ur code. I mean I want  this image align center vertically

Comment: Hmmm, then something else might be at play. Did you update the `width` from the `span.icons` CSS?

Comment: I guess the width does not matter. I use ur example, and it still not works

Comment: Then we need to know more about the surrounding HTML and CSS as it seems that other elements are affecting this class. add a `border: 1px solid green;` to the `.icons` class and see where the borders are

Comment: Thanks, when I click that fullpage link and open your html in browser, it works, but when I copy the code to my page and run it, it just not work, and they are running in same browser

Comment: That's very strange.  what's different between your page and my code?

Comment: This is so strange, when I paste same html inside stackoverflow's code snippet runner, it works very well while it does not work in my local even I use same browser( if u run the html in my question, it works, that is the same html I copy from my local)!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104468/discussion-between-ochi-and-kuan).

Comment: I add a screen shot of my local

Comment: @Kuan you have not added the extra css rule (for the image itself)

Comment: yeah, I also did not add it in the html in my question,  but that works( just run the html in my question, u can see it works well)

Answer (score -2):

Just try adding

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5ky6jLuj/1/